# How to make matplotlib contour plot when z is not a function of x and y?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I am trying to make a contour plot of a geographical feature using matplotlib. I have data for the x, y, and z coordinates of about 47 points on this geographical feature. z is not a function of x and y. The documentation and guides I have read indicate that matplotlib only can make a contour plot if z is some function of x and y.

My question is: how do I make a contour plot on matplotlib with the x, y, and z points I have, where z ≠ f(x,y)?

Comment: Contour only requires z be a 2-d array, not that it can be generated analytically from x and y.  If your z data is the same dimensions as your x and y data ( ie your data is not ona grid) then try tricontour.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation at https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html, you'll see that the contour method accepts `x`, `y`, and `z` values as arrays.  It doesn't care where `z` came from.